# symfony2 logout

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

My problem is capture user logout. the code what i have is:

```
public  function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception){

    return new Response($this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage()));
}

public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $empleado = $token->getUser();
    $log = new Log();
    $log->setFechalog(new \DateTime('now'));
    $log->setTipo("Out");
    $log->setEntidad("");
    $log->setEmpleado($empleado);
    $this->em->persist($log);
    $this->em->flush();
}

public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) {
    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));
}
```

The problem is I can not access the user token `TokenInterface` when you are running the logout function?

Comment: the soluction problem is the service security context thanks.

Comment: Is `$token->getUser()` returning null? Or the `$token` is null?

Answer (score 13):

To get token, you must inject with security context.

**1. Create class Logout listener, something like this:**

```
namespace Yourproject\Yourbundle\Services;
...
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface {

  private $security;  

  public function __construct(SecurityContext $security) {
    $this->security = $security;
  }

  public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) {
     $user = $this->security->getToken()->getUser();

     //add code to handle $user here
     //...

     $response =  RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));

    return $response;
  }
}
```

**2. And then in service.yml, add this line:**

```
....
logout_listener:
   class:  Yourproject\Yourbundle\Services\LogoutListener
   arguments:  [@security.context]
```

That's it, may it helps.

Comment: This won't work, for logout_listener service you have no defined event. So the listener won't be fired at all.

Comment: @artworkadシ, i have registered this event on service.yml, so it will be fired when user do logout. i have used this on several project symphony, and there is no problem.

Comment: In my opinion it is necessary adding ALSO the lines in the answer on Jul 24 '14 at 15:22. It worked for me at symfony 2.5.

Comment: In Symfony 3 you have to use `['@security.authorization_checker']` instead of `security.context`

Answer (score 8):

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

security.yml

```
secured_area:

    logout:
        path:   /logout
        **success_handler: logout_listener**
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here were you can overwrite any controller of the bundle:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html