# How to override logout action in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I know logout action can be performed by symfony2 security controller by default.
when we give the path Logout like this it works fine.

but I need to perform some action like storing some data into the database when logout is happened.So how can i achieve this thing.

If any have an idea please help me.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/iJ9Kq72aTgM).

Answer (score 9):

you need to define new rule for logout action in routing.yml or annotation (it`s up to you)

```
logout_user:
    pattern:  /logoutUser
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:YourController:logout }
```

Then it`s only writing code for this action like this:

```
public function logoutAction() {
        //do whatever you want here 

        //clear the token, cancel session and redirect
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
    }
```

There is also way to do the job proposed by tesmojones
here [symfony2 logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743213/symfony2-logout)