# getUser() in Logout with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use "**success_handler**" (in Symfony security.yml) and **onLogoutSuccess()** with FOSUserBundle. But I want to getUser() for add his name in flash message.

**Service and PHP Classe :**

```
services:
    utilisateur_deconnexion:
        class: UtilisateurBundle\Handler\Deconnexion
        arguments: [@router]

class Deconnexion implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) 
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Vous êtes à présent déconnecté.');
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dometech_index_index'));
    }

}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743213/symfony2-logout . You can add "SecurityContext $security" in your constructor and use it to get user. Add in security.yml [@security.context] in arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can inject `@security.context` service into your logout handler.
From the [SecurityContext](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/SecurityContext.html) you will be able to get currently set token object which is instance of [TokenInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.html). From the instance of `TokenInterface` you will be able to get the current user. See below.

**services.yml**

```
services:
    utilisateur_deconnexion:
        class: UtilisateurBundle\Handler\Deconnexion
        arguments: ["@router", "@security.context"]
```

**Logout success handler:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class Deconnexion implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    private $router;

    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) 
    {
         // let's assume your user object has getUsername method
         $username = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername(); 

         $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
             'success', 
             sprintf('%s - Vous êtes à présent déconnecté.', $username)
         );

         return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dometech_index_index'));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete/update the post of [@takeit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757871/2146064) for Symfony 3.x

Replace `@security.context` to `@security.token_storage`

**services.yml**

```
services:
    utilisateur_deconnexion:
        class: UtilisateurBundle\Handler\Deconnexion
        arguments: ["@router", "@security.token_storage"]
```

**Logout success handler:**

```
[...]
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request) 
    {
         // let's assume your user object has getUsername method
         $username = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUsername(); 

         [...]
    }
[...]
```